# Explain the different navigation types, Android

Tags: android, navigation

I've been setting up an app for awhile now and now that I know exactly what I'm doing, I'm ready to pretty much restart and make a new version that's more user-friendly. While creating the app, Eclipse want to know what navigation type I want.

```
None
Tabs
Tabs+Swipe
Swipe View+Title Strip
Dropdown
```

Can somebody either explain (or give a link to something that explains) what the bottom four options look like and how to use them? So far all I've used is the 'none' option and I simply used buttons and a menu to navigate. I'd like to learn about the other options to make my app as sleek as possible.

--This part was answered: http://android-er.blogspot.com/2012/06/various-navigation-type-provided-in-new.html

But the 2nd part of this question:
Is is possible to have one navigation at one point in time and another type of navigation at a different time?

Example: Start-splash screen, go to login screen. Once logged in, go to a menu. If they pick 'edit forms', it brings them to a `Swipe Views + Title Strip` setup where each different view is a different form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you want? It was the first search result. http://android-er.blogspot.com/2012/06/various-navigation-type-provided-in-new.html

Comment: Thanks. I did search on Google, but I only found the Android Developers page which didn't really help. The link you provided is extremely useful. I'm editing the question now because I only actually posted half of the question and forgot to post the second half - sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you are looking for?
[Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/training/design-navigation/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

As the first part of your question has been answered and i cannot yet comment, i will consider this an "answer" to your second question:

It is not typically considered appropriate to post multi-part questions on Stack Overflow. Why you may ask? For situations exactly like this one. You have half your question answered and accepted that answer as the correct one, However... What of the second question? What if someone decides to answer it and gives a good answer. Only one person may have their answer marked as correct. And considering that those ratings change the level of interaction you may have on Stack Overflow, It would be wrong to accept one half and not the other simply because they were given by 2 different people.

If you have a question that is in some way a subset of your first, leave a comment on the answer in which you need elaboration. ie: (Question 1 = "What is a class?"; Question 2 = "Why would i need such a functionality?";)

If you have a question that is a fork in your first thought, create a new question. ie: (Question 1 = "What is a class?"; Question 2 = "What does it mean to instantiate an object?";)

If the core subject matter is different, you should create a new question. Otherwise you leave a comment. But never put 2 questions in 1 unless they would have the same problem / solution.

anyways...best wishes, on a year old post =P